# Java Plist XML Parsing

Tags: java, xml, plist

I'm parsing a (not well formed) Apple Plist File with java.

My Code looks like this:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream( "foo" ); 
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance(); 
XMLEventReader parser = factory.createXMLEventReader( in ); 
while (parser.hasNext()){    
XMLEvent event = parser.nextEvent();    
  //code to navigate the nodes 
}
```

The parts I"m parsing are looking like this:

```
<dict>    
  <key>foo</key><integer>123</integer>
  <key>bar</key><string>Boom &amp; Shroom</string>
</dict>
```

My problem is now, that  nodes containing a ampersand are not parsed like they should because the ampersand is representing a entity.

What can i do to get the value of the  node as a complete String, instead of broken parts?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The nodes should be parsed just fine, but you might get multiple events representing "Boom ", "&amp;" and " Shroom", depending on the implementation. You need to be able to handle that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Indeed i get multiple events, but i just want to get one event representing the complete String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to solve your problem by setting the `IS_COALESCING` property on the `XMLInputFactory` (I also prefer `XMLStreamReader` over `XMLEventReader`, but ymmv):

```
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
factory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING, Boolean.TRUE);

InputStream in = // ...
xmlReader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(in, "UTF-8");
```

Incidentally, to the best of my knowledge none of the JDK parsers will handle "not well formed" XML without choking. Your XML is, in fact, well-formed: it uses an entity rather than a raw ampersand.

Answer (score 1):

There is a predefined method `getElementText()`, which is buggy in jdk1.6.0_15, but works ok with jdk1.6.0_19. A complete program to easily parse the plist file is this:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;

public class Parser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws XMLStreamException, IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream("foo.xml");
        XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLEventReader parser = factory.createXMLEventReader(in);

        assert parser.nextEvent().isStartDocument();

        XMLEvent event = parser.nextTag();
        assert event.isStartElement();
        final String name1 = event.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart();

        if (name1.equals("dict")) {
            while ((event = parser.nextTag()).isStartElement()) {
                final String name2 = event.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart();

                if (name2.equals("key")) {
                    String key = parser.getElementText();
                    System.out.println("key: " + key);

                } else if (name2.equals("integer")) {
                    String number = parser.getElementText();
                    System.out.println("integer: " + number);

                } else if (name2.equals("string")) {
                    String str = parser.getElementText();
                    System.out.println("string: " + str);
                }
            }
        }

        assert parser.nextEvent().isEndDocument();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> This library enables your Java application to handle property lists of various formats.

> Read / write property lists from / to files, streams or byte arrays
> Convert between property list formats
> Property list contents are provided as objects from the NeXTSTEP environment (NSDictionary, NSArray, NSString, etc.)
> Serialize native java data structures to property list objects
> Deserialize from property list objects to native java data structures

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.googlecode.plist</groupId>
  <artifactId>dd-plist</artifactId>
  <version>1.26</version>
</dependency>
```

[dd-plist](https://github.com/3breadt/dd-plist)