# How do I read this kind of XML-File in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an app for the iPhone and now I want to use it on Android. The problem is: I can't work with the given XML-File.

[Here's a link to the XML-File](http://www.10000flies.de/?format=plist)

Normally I would go through every node, but this won't work here since it seems like a key-value xml-file that also contains arrays.

How can I achieve it in Android/Java now that I can read this data.

Comment: I don't see why you can't work with it. It's normal XML, use XPath or some XML parser.

Comment: duplicate of [Apple pList form of XML can I parse it through Android Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904418/apple-plist-form-of-xml-can-i-parse-it-through-android-java) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632320/how-to-get-the-values-from-plist-in-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484163/how-to-parse-plist-file-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451170/java-plist-xml-parsing and othes. You might also consider using a search engine to search for `java xml plist parser` to find other libraries for this.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - The problem is that this plist has an array inside an array - Scores. I don't know how to handle this. I can handle simple plist files when they are normally ordered, but I have problems reading them out when they got a string inside an array inside a string inside an array

Answer (score 1):

This type of XML file is called *plist* in iOS and OS X - short for *property list*.  The easiest way to deal with it is by using XMLWise library.  It's open source and is hosted on code.google.com - [here is the link](http://code.google.com/p/xmlwise/).

It has a simple method for reading in the entire file and parsing it into a HashMap, something like this:

```
String xmlData = ...;
HashMap<?, ?> hashMap = (HashMap<?, ?>) Plist.objectFromXml(xmlData);
```